# If I assign an Object as GameObject, I cant get the RectTransform to work. How to fix that?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I want to give my Parent GameObject *Inventory* spicific rec-coordinates via this line of code:
`Inventory.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = new Vector3(500f, 0f, 0f);`

In the editor, the object *Inventory* is assigned as a GameObject, so it keeps changing the rec-coordinates to world-coordinates. I've tried assigning the *Inventory* as a *Transform* and *RectTransform* but it says that there is a missmatch in the type.

How can I fix that, either by fixing my code or by assigning it as something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify the RectTransform's localPosition:

```
Inventory.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3(500f, 0f, 0f);
```

---

Even **without** `RectTransform` (localPositions seems to be inherited/shared between Transform&RectTransform):

```
Inventory.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(500f, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `anchoredPosition` to move `RectTransform` object.

```cs
GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector2(500f, 0);
```

Remember that its variable takes `Vector2`.